# Eclipse[HELIOS] CDT: Autocomplete, STLs not working with Eclipse ..HELP!

Tags: c++, eclipse, stl, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am a java user but wanted to play around with CPP so I installed CDT plugin for eclipse [HELIOS].

I am facing some issues trying to configure it correctly and am wondering if someone can help me. Here is a short code we can use:

```
  #include "Base.h"
// These lines give error => Unresolved inclusion: <vector>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    void Base::ininitalizeVector()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            bIntVector.insert(i); //after pressing "." no method names etc appear
        }
    }
```

1] The auto complete feature doesnt work for STLs . 
2] I cant get a list of supported methods etc after I hit dot"."
3] Includes do not work: #include 
4] I think using namespace std is enough for STLs to work , but guess not enough for IDE support ?. Do I even need to say #include

I did rightclick project => rebuild indexes but that didnt help
In my project=> general=>source location: the source folder is the folder that has this CPP file and the header file.

I probably havent configured things correctly , any help ?

Infact , if there is someother IDE which works quickly out of the box, I will be happy to try that out. All I want is some IDE support so that I can verify things while I read on cpp.

Thanks

- This is where I got the CDT: 
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/helios/
- I am running eclipse on Windows off a
  folder: C:\USER\setups\eclipse

Comment: If the IDE has 'Unresolved inclusions' it means that the header you've supplied cannot be found, so it cannot perform autocomplete.

Comment: Right, but the header is one of the std library. How do I add it ? I was assuming that STLs should some with CDT plugin. Interestingly I can still use the STLs after I use namespace std

Comment: Only files related to CDT are included with it.  If you're on Linux your C++ STL files will be somewhere like /usr/include/c++/4.5

Comment: I am on windows. Updated that in the question.Couldnt find STLs in the eclipse folder

Comment: This will help you out: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-stlcdt/index.html

Comment: @cbamber85: I didn't find anything useful for this case at that link. And, in future, if you try to write an answer, don't do it as a comment, do it as an Answer.

Comment: @akavel Agreed, I should have made an answer and will do, however at the time I wasn't sure if I was on the right track.  Also the article I linked quite plainly states you need Cygwin for GNU tools on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Unresolved inclusions in CODAN, no autocompletion for the types linked to the headers in question, all mean that Eclipse cannot find the headers you are requesting in the places you told it in the project settings.  On Linux the STL headers are usually in `/usr/include/c++/<GCC Version>`.  However on Windows the STL headers are not shipped with it (nor any GNU tools either), so you have 'fake' a Linux environment by installing [Cygwin](http:///www.cygwin.com/).

Windows development is always easier in Visual Studio - they were designed for each other after all.